# Escaping html in Jquery

Tags: jquery, escaping

I have a simple jquery snippet here:

```
$("#someid").html("Text Here");
```

The only problem I am having is that I am putting Database data inside the `html()`.

```
$("#someid").html("<?php echo $row['tablecolumn']; ?>");
```

It works great!  Except for one thing.
It does not show when I have 'breaks' in the text from the database.

I'm sure I need to do some sort of escaping of characters.  But I don't know quiet what that is.
Any ideas out there?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify your example, the PHP code makes it a bit confusing. What is that doing there, is it filled in on runtime? Can you show us what you are inserting and doesn't work? Do you mean `<br>` style line breaks`? Can you examine the HTML code in your browser's "view source" mode, paste it into your question and show us what's wrong?

Comment: if you check the edits, that's not the OP's question. Rolling back..

Comment: No Jason, the PHP code was there, but un`code`d which is why it's not visible in the history view. Rolled back your rollback :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/nl2br) to add HTML line breaks to the physical ones and encode the data with [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
$("#someid").html(<?php echo json_encode(nl2br($row['tablecolumn'])); ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, your text does not show up with line breaks as you'd expect?

Perhaps you need to convert the line breaks to 
 tags on the server side before sending the data over. If you're using PHP for instance, you could use the [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function for to create HTML line breaks anywhere there is a \n in the text.

Comment: I was first applying the nl2br function, and got the same result, nothing returned.

Gumbo was right about his entry:
$("#someid").html(<?php echo json_encode(nl2br($row['tablecolumn'])); ?>);

that worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

From [jQuery Attributes/text](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text)

> Set the text contents of all matched
>   elements. Similar to html(), but
>   escapes HTML (replace "<" and ">" with
>   their HTML entities). Cannot be used
>   on input elements. For input field
>   text use the val attribute.